# log4net problem under my solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

Under my VS2010 solution I've this situation:

- WEBSITE
- Library1
- Library2

On global.asax.cs I initialize the log4net configuration using:

```
private static log4net.ILog _logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("globalASAX");

void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    _logger.Info("[APPLICATION START] " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
}
```

It works fine and Application start message is correclty available on log.txt file. The problem happens when I try to use log something on the classes available on DLL Library1 or Library2.

I added the row:

```
private static log4net.ILog _logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ImageRepository));
```

but when I try to all the _logger.error("blabla") nothing happens on log file; all properties of _logger are false (i.e. isdebugenable=false). How can I fix that? I followed the instruction available here:

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html

the configuration of log4net is under web.config file:

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
            <conversionPattern value="log\explorer-log-%date{ yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss}-[%processid].log"/>
        </file>
        <appendToFile value="true"/>
        <maximumFileSize value="1024KB"/>
        <maxSizeRollBackups value="5"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
    </root>
</log4net>
```

anyone can help me?
thanks,
Andrea

Comment: What does your log4net config look like?

Comment: is it possibile this problem happens when configuration tags are under web.config file instead of a separated file?

Comment: I'm able to write log if I write from website (where I call the XmlConfigurator.Configure() but doesn't work if I call from another project under the same solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect log4net cannot find the logger for your type **ImageRepository**. As a quick check create a named logger and try calling it.

```
private static log4net.ILog _logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("FooLog");
```

And config

```
<root>
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
</root>
<logger name="FooLog">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: I'm able to write log if I write from website (where I call the XmlConfigurator.Configure() but doesn't work if I call from another project under the same solution

Comment: @Andrea I see, as you said you store log4net config in the same config for the project (like web.config). This is why you can have this problem. Config files  are not necessarily picked up from the same project (for example for dll projects). As a solution: try moving log4net config to a separate file and load that file. Make sure it is copied to the Bin folders of the projects where you use it. This shall solve your problem.

Comment: I solved passing the _logger object to the constructor of external class. It's working fine, I know it may not be a good solution

Comment: @Andrea good stuff, you can also do constructor injection and inversion of control with it - will be a  fine approach

Answer (score 0):

In theory this should work (as I'm sure you are aware).  In general, however, there are two areas to check when you don't get anything logged to a file.  The first area I would check would be the file appender itself.  Text files can be locked, which can cause messages to be lost.  The other thing I would check is to be sure that log4net is properly initialized in the library.  It should be, but it doesn't hurt to check.  If neither of these solutions help, try turning on the debugging of log4net itself to see what error messages are coming up.  Here is a link that shows you how to turn on those messages:

http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx

Comment: I'm able to write log if I write from website (where I call the XmlConfigurator.Configure() but doesn't work if I call from another project under the same solution

Comment: @Andrea Girardi - Understood.  However, the website might be holding a lock on your text file or you aren't properly initializing log4net inside your library.  Check the first by writing to the console.  If that works in your library, the issue is locking of the file.  If it doesn't work, check to be sure you are actually initializing log4net properly inside your library.  If both don't work, turn on debugging of log4net itself to see where the issue is.